# Mips: Error #9: Break instruction executed when I try to print a string

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to just print some strings as I learn assembly, but when I run my program I'm seeing this error:

```
Error #9: Break instruction executed
Fault address: 0040028

Current instruction: 00bad0d (at 00400028)
Decoded instruction: break
```

Here's my code

```
         .data
         .align 4
banner:  .asciiz "*********\n"

         .text
         .align 4
         .globl main


main:
         jal   print_str  #print the string

print_str:
         addi  $sp, $sp, -16 
         sw    $ra, 12($sp)
         sw    $s2, 8($sp)
         sw    $s1, 4($sp)
         sw    $s0, 0($sp)

         la    $a0, banner
         li    $v0, 4
         syscall
```

I tried to debug myself, I took a look at inside the .lst for the instruction at 00400028 but I cannot find it.

Comment: I guess it means that the execution reached at end of program and there are no instruction to execute there. Try exiting the program explicitly via system call.

Comment: @MikeCAT You were correct, exiting with systemcall fixed it.